# Inserting html tags between C# block code in cshtml file

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I want to use html tags between C# block code, I've tried it but I got errors.
How can I insert html tags  between C# block code in cshtml file?

The error is:

> only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions
>   can be used as a statement
>
> only assignment call increment decrement await and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement
>   [image]

```
@{
    Func<List<Comment>, Comment, HelperResult> ShowTree = null;
    ShowTree = (items, node) =>
    {
        @<text>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var comment in items)
                {

                }
            </ul>
         </text>;
        return null;
    };

}
```

> Update:When I move the text outside the {}, I encountered some errors, too. 
>   Look at this picture.
>   [image]

**Update 2:**
I've used `@:` but still there is a problem. that is `;expected`

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

```
@{
Func<List<Comment>, Comment, int, HelperResult> ShowTree = null;
ShowTree = (items, parentItem, parentId) =>
{
    var count = items.Count(p => p.ParentId == parentId);
    if (count > 0)
    {
        @:<ul>
            foreach (var item in items.Where(p => p.ParentId == 
 parentId).ToList())
            {
            @:<li>
                string collapseId = string.Format("collapse_{0}", item.Id);
                @:<a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" 
 href="#@{collapseId}" aria-expanded="True" aria-controls="@{collapseId}">
                    @:<span class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"> 
 Commenter Name</span>
                @:</a>
                    @:<div class="collapse show" id="@{collapseId}">
                        @:<div class="card">
                                @:<p>item.Description</p>
                        @:</div>
                            ShowTree(items, item, item.Id);
                    @:</div>
            @:</li>
            }
        @:</ul>
    }
    return null;
  };
};
```

**Update 3: Latest codes with error messages in browser**

```
@using Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Helper
@using Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
@using Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Helper
@model List<Comment>

@{
   Func<List<Comment>, Comment, int, HelperResult> ShowTree = null;
   ShowTree = (items, parentItem, parentId) =>
   {
   var count = items.Count(p => p.ParentId == parentId);
   if (count > 0)
   {
   @:<ul>
   @<text>@{
        foreach (var item in items.Where(p => p.ParentId ==    
   parentId).ToList())
        {
            string collapseId = string.Format("collapse_{0}", item.Id);
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="@collapseId" aria-expanded="True" aria-controls="@collapseId">
                <span class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"> Commenter Name</span></a>
                <div class="collapse show" id="@collapseId"><div class="card"><p>@item.Description</p></div>
                    @ShowTree(items, item, item.Id);
                </div>
            </li>
        }
}</text>

@:</ul>
}
return null;
};
}


 @{
 Func<List<Comment>, HelperResult> CreateTree = null;
 CreateTree = commentList => new Func<List<Comment>, HelperResult>(
 @<text>@{
    List<Comment> nodesRoot = commentList.Where(p => p.ParentId == 
 null).ToList();
    <ul>
        @foreach (var comment in nodesRoot)
        {
            <li>
                <p>@comment.Description</p>
                @ShowTree(commentList, comment, comment.Id);
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
  }
   </text>)(null);
  }

<div class="media mb-4">
<div class="media-body">
    @CreateTree(Model)
</div>

</div>
```

[image: Latest codes]

[image: Error messages that shows in browser]

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   process this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>   Generated Code
>
> ; expected

Answer (score 7):

For inline escape from C# codeblock in `cshtml` use `@:`. For example:

```
@{
    Func<List<Comment>, Comment, HelperResult> ShowTree = null;
    ShowTree = (items, node) =>
    {
        @:<ul>
            foreach (var comment in items)
                {

                }
        @:</ul>
        return null;
    };
}
```

Comment: It seems your answer is near to right answer but still there is a problem! Please look at the new Update 2.

Comment: @Jahan Why you are using new C# codeblock in C# codeblock? Use normal `@`. For example: `@:<a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" 
 href="#@collapseId" aria-expanded="True" aria-controls="@collapseId">`

Comment: Now, I've used normal @. but still there are problems in lines 15, 18, 26, 29 and 31.

Comment: @Jahan Error lines suggest problem with break lines. When using inline escape (`@:`) you need to do all in one line. For example try this: https://pastebin.com/raw/mQxQ5V50

Comment: I wrote same as your code exactly, but still there are problems!! Can you check the code in your Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: @Jahan I checked twice as normal view (cshtml: https://pastebin.com/raw/HkTz1aHm, result: https://image.ibb.co/gE3hZ6/dontbefoolidiot.png) and for me working (VS15.5 + .Net Core 2.0.5). At the end - don't use `!!` next time, it's not normal

Comment: I checked your code. That is correct but when you add Func<List<Comment>, Comment, int, HelperResult> ShowTree = null;
    ShowTree = (items, parentItem, parentId) =>{

in the first of your code ,after @{,  you will see the errors!!  It seems THAT RELATED TO declare FUNC !!!

Answer (score 2):

As I see you want to render some content by mixing Html with C# code, instead of inserting your C# code in cshtml file you can create custom Html helper, it will be something like this:

```
     public static class CustomHtmlHelper
        {
            public static IHtmlContent ShowTree(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
            {
                Func<List<Comment>, Comment, HelperResult> ShowTree = null;

                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                ShowTree = (items, node) =>
                {
                    builder.Append("<ul>");

                    foreach (var comment in items)
                    {
                        builder.Append("<li>"+comment.Content+"</li>");

                    }
                    builder.Append("</ul>");
                    return null;
                };

                //Just for testing purposes only

                var comments = new List<Comment> { new Comment { Content = "Comment 1" }, new Comment { Content = "Comment 2" } };

                ShowTree(comments, new Comment());

                //
                return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());

            }
        }
```

- In cshtml

  @Html.ShowTree()

Comment: I want to implement the code just only in cshtml file without creating class.

Comment: @Jahan: Why though? Ahmed has given you a elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: @garfbradaz: The Ahmad's answer is correct but I want just an implementation in cshtml file.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the `<text>` and `<ul>` outside the `{}`. Like this :

```
<text>
<ul>
    @{
        Func<List<Comment>, Comment, HelperResult> ShowTree = null;
        ShowTree = (items, node) =>
        {

            foreach (var comment in items)
            {
            }
            return null;
        };

    }
</ul>
</text>;
```

Separe your code in multiple bracket

```
@{
    var commentList = new List<string>();
}
<text>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var comment in commentList)
        {
            <li>@comment</li>
        }

    </ul>
</text>;
```

Comment: Ok I think you should try to stock your items in a variable in one @{} and after that use the @foreach(){} . So don't try to put everything in one @{}. see my edit for simple example

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution that was not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Can it help you?

```
@{
Func<List<Comment>, Comment, int, HelperResult> ShowTree = null;

ShowTree = (items, parentItem, parentId) =>
{
var count = items.Count(p => p.ParentId == parentId);
if (count > 0)
{
        @:<ul>
    foreach (var item in items.Where(p => p.ParentId == parentId).ToList())
{
    string collapseId = string.Format("collapse_{0}", item.Id);
            @<text>
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse"
                   href="@{collapseId}" aria-expanded="True" aria-controls="@{collapseId}">
                    <span class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"> Commenter Name</span>
                </a>
                <div class="collapse show" id="@{collapseId}">
                    <div class="card">
                        <p>@item.Description</p>

                    </div>
                    @ShowTree(items, item, item.Id);
                </div>
            </li>
            </text>
                    }
@:</ul>
}
return null;
};
}
```

Comment: Please look at the Update 3.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `@` before `<text>`.

Comment: When I remove the @ before <text> I get another errors: "The name 'text' does not exist in the current context. Cannot resolve symbol 'text'